# Keeping a native (C) pointer into an object instance -- and cleaning it up afterwards

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, pam

For one of my projects, I want to implement a complete PAM implementation for Java (application side and module side as well).

Right now, I'm on the application side. I took jpam as a base but I stumble upon a problem, and after some hours of searching around I still cannot find the solution to my problem :/

This is the current code:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_org_eel_kitchen_pam_PamHandle_authenticate(
    JNIEnv *pEnv, jobject pObj, jstring pServiceName, jstring pUsername,
    jstring pPassword, jboolean debug)
{
    pam_handle_t *pamh = NULL;
    int retval;

    /*
     * TODO: unclear, see what's what
     *
     * With my first tests, it appears that GetStringUTFChars() makes the JVM
     * crash if memory cannot be allocated... But an array copy was made. See
     * what happens if the JVM decides NOT to make a copy. Right now it is
     * assumed that allocations succeed. And the JNI spec says
     * GetStringUTFChars() does NOT throw an OOM on failure.
     */
    service_name = (*pEnv)->GetStringUTFChars(pEnv, pServiceName, NULL);
    username = (*pEnv)->GetStringUTFChars(pEnv, pUsername, NULL);
    password = (*pEnv)->GetStringUTFChars(pEnv, pPassword, NULL);

    /* Get a handle to a PAM instance */
    retval = pam_start(service_name, username, &PAM_converse, &pamh);

    if (retval != PAM_SUCCESS) {
        pr_debug("pam_start failed for service %s: %s\n", service_name,
            pam_strerror(NULL, retval));
        goto out_nohandle;
    }

    pam_set_item(pamh, PAM_AUTHTOK, password);
    retval = pam_authenticate(pamh, 0);

    /* Is user permitted access? */
    if (retval != PAM_SUCCESS) {
        pr_debug("failed to authenticate user %s: %s\n", username,
            pam_strerror(NULL, retval));
        goto out_free;
    }

    retval = pam_acct_mgmt(pamh, 0);

    if (retval != PAM_SUCCESS)
        pr_debug("failed to setup account for user %s: %s\n", username,
            pam_strerror(NULL, retval));

out_free:
    /* Clean up our handles and variables */
    if (pam_end(pamh, retval) != PAM_SUCCESS) {
        pamh = NULL;
        pr_debug("Fuchs! Failed to release PAM handle\n");
    }

out_nohandle:
    (*pEnv)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(pEnv, pServiceName, service_name);
    (*pEnv)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(pEnv, pUsername, username);
    (*pEnv)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(pEnv, pPassword, password);

    return retval;
}
```

What I want here is keep a reference to `pamh` for all instances of `PamHandle`. How is this done?

**edit**: OK, I have the answer to this, and now there's the cleanup part: do I use `finalize()` to call a native cleanup method then `super.finalize();`, or is there a JNI function which is triggered by the GC which I can/must implement?

Comment: It's not clear what you want:  If you want to keep a C pointer in a Java object, you generally assign it to a `long`.

Comment: @HotLicks I want to ensure that each instance of a `PamHandle` will have a unique `pamh` as its disposal. If I understand @Als correctly, I can just change its scope to the file and each instance will have its own...

Comment: @fge You cannot have the GC clean up that pointer reliably. One popular way to do it in java  is to derive from [Closable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html).Then, in your finalizer you call close, just incase they didn't, but you also spam in your logs about not calling close.

Comment: @EthanSteinberg OK, thank you for the information, I'll go another way then!

Comment: @fge Oops, Closable is outdated. [AutoClosable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) is the newer better version.

Comment: @EthanSteinberg yes, however AutoCloseable, if I read correctly, is only meant to be used in try-with-resource statements... I'll reread the Javadoc since you make me doubt _again_ on this one...

Comment: @fge The way I read it is that it can be used in a try-with-resource statement as an extra feature. I think the idea is that if you have all of your classes use AutoClosable, then all of your classes "magically" get the extra syntactical sugar of try-with-resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a long to store a pointer to pam_handle_t.

Java-side it would look like

```
long handle = Pam.create();
Pam.DoSomething(handle,arg1,arg2);
```

Of course you could encapsulate this inside a class, so you could have the interface.

```
PamHandle p = new PamHandle();
p.DoSomething(arg1,arg2);
```

C side it would look like this:

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_org_Create(
    JNIEnv *pEnv)
{
    pam_handle_t *pamh = createNew pam_handle somehow
    jlong result = (jlong) pamh;
    return result;
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_org_Blah_Blah_blah(
    JNIEnv *pEnv, jlong handle, jstring arg1,jstring arg2)
{
    pam_handle_t *pamh = (pam_handle_t*)handle;
 // ... Do rest of stuff
}
```

This would allow you to have one pam_handle_t per instance.
It is also alot more performant to manually pass the integer each time, rather than passing an object, and then having to access the object's field.

**EDIT**

Also, if you are worried about the jlong not being able to hold a pointer correctly, a jlong is guaranteed to be 64-bit. So, a jlong will work for this case all the way until we start getting 128-bit integers( a long long way away).

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I need to ask another question about how to trigger the GC to clean up that pointer as well...

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases here:
Currently, Your pointer is local to the function and it cannot be used beyond the scope of the function. Note that if all your newly created functions will be called through a function which will be called through the function in which you currently declared `pamh` then you can just keep on passing the pointer as function parameters.

However,If your case is not as mentioned above then you will have to make `pamh` glbal so that it remains valid throughout the life of the program and then you can use it accross different functions.

You will have to declare,

```
pam_handle_t *pamh = NULL;
```

as a global.

Note that making it global would mean you ensure access to it is synchronized in case your program is multithreaded.

Comment: OK, I know about variable scoping in C... But JNI not so much. You mean a new `pamh` will be created for each instantiated object?

Comment: @fge: No, I didin't mean a new `pamh` being created for every object, that would defeat the purpose.If you use a global then it is the same `pamh` which will be alive throughout the life of the progrma.

Comment: It basically creates a singleton. 
He can only ever have one pam instance, he loses thread safety, and it adds yet more global state to keep track of.

Comment: @EthanSteinberg: Creating a variable at global scope makes it singleton? not really! Thread safety is a concern already pointed out in the answer.

Comment: @Als Ok, lets say that he decides that he wants this functionality in another module of the same program, but a different session. This solution makes that sharing impossible.

Comment: Also, looking at the pam interface itself, http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/8329799/pam_start.htm#tagmref_pam_start, it looks like he needs a session almost for every user he wants to authenticate as.